# Dictionary Contains QuestionMaks

Tags: c#, .net

I have a simple question. During i create a dictionary in c#, half of the dictionary contains question marks. Here is my situration:[image]

SourceCode:

```
/// <summary>
/// Get Member
/// </summary>
/// <param name="Binder"></param>
/// <param name="Result"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder Binder, out object Result)
{
    if (Binder.Name == "AsDictionary")
    {
        IDictionary<string, string> cValues = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        foreach (var cValue in myValues)
        {
            string cVal = "";
            if (cValue.Value == null)
            {
                cVal = "";
            }
            else
            {
                cVal = cValue.Value.ToString();
            }

            cValues.Add(cValue.Key, cVal);
        }

        Result = cValues;
        return true;
    }

    int cCount = myValues.Where(Item => Item.Key.ToLower() == Binder.Name.ToLower()).ToList().Count;

    if (cCount == 0)
    {
        Result = null;
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        Result = myValues.Where(Item => Item.Key.ToLower() == Binder.Name.ToLower()).First().Value;
    }

    return true;
}
```

myValues is also a ObservableCollection:

```
private ObservableCollection<DynamicSqlValue> myValues;
```

DynamicSqlValue is a very simple class:

```
public class DynamicSqlValue
{
    public string Key
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public object Value
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Show your code as a text, not as an image.

Comment: why you are using object as Result? Why won't you use Dictionary?

Comment: "Show your code as a text, not as an image.": Done
"why you are using object as Result?": Because the result is not always a Dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Must be some kind of visual studio issue or maybe you're running out of memory. Have you tried logging the values?

I would go a step farther than Patryk and ask why you aren't doing myValues.ToDictionary.  Also, the .Where, .ToList, and .Count should be as simple as:

```
 myValues.Any(kvp => kvp.Key.Equals(Binder.Name, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
```

That function should really only be like 4 or 5 lines of code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have logged all values and they are correct. I will try your solution! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's not answer for Your question (sorry for that) but i have some refactor tip of Your code:

Make Your foreach like that:

```
foreach (var cValue in myValues)
{
    cValues.Add(cValue.Key, cValue.Value != null ? cValue.Value.ToString() : string.Empty);
}
```

And create local variable from linq query:

```
var binderMyValues = myValues.Where(Item => Item.Key.ToLower() == Binder.Name.ToLower());
```

to use it like e.g.

```
int cCount = binderMyValues.ToList().Count;
```

or...

```
Result = binderMyValues.First().Value;
```